# OpenSubtab throws error when embedding a VF page in lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console, subtab-apps

Javascript on VF page:

```
    function openInSubtab(asd, asdf) {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function (r) {
                callBackopenTab(r, asd, asdf);
            });
    }

    function callBackopenTab(r, asd, asdf) {
        console.log('rId : ' + r.id);
        console.log('asd: ' + asd);
        console.log('asdf: ' + asdf);
        sforce.console.openSubtab(r.id, '/' + asd, true, asdf, null);
    }
```

VF page link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"openInSubtab('{!asd', '{!asdf');return false;">{!asd}</a>
```

This works fine when its a VF page and we include this into a flexipage. Now I have embedded this VF page in a lightning component via an iframe.

```
<iframe id="componentName" src="/apex/VFPAGENAME" width="100%"
        height="100%" frameBorder="0"/>
```

Now when I click the link, it throws:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://******.my.salesforce.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Object.handleOnload (https://******/support/console/xdomain/30.0/iframeinterface.js:1:356)
at window.onload (https://******/support/console/xdomain/30.0/crossDomainProxy.html:4:89)
```

and does not open anything in subtab.

**UPDATE**

I suspect the reason could be that my console app is opened in `lightning` experience, thus the url in address bar has lightning in it, where as `window.location.href` still gives me base url of my org, so it may be a same origin policy, but still dont know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

VF page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
   onClick="openCustomSubtab('asdf', 'asdfg');return false;">OpenSubtab</a>
```

Javascript :

```
function openCustomSubtab(id, tabName) {

    var response = {
        destinationID: "destId",
        paramObject: {
            id: id,
            tabName: tabName
        }
    };
    parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(response), '*');

}
```

Then listen to this message in my controller of the lightning component where my VF page is embedded.

```
doInit: function (component) {
    var listener = function (event) {

        if (event !== null && event.data !== null && typeof event.data === 'string') {
            try {
                var eventResponse = JSON.parse(event.data);
                if (eventResponse.destinationID !== '' && eventResponse.destinationID === 'destId'){
                    var someTest = setInterval(function () {
                        var idContact = component.get("v.recordId");
                        var workspaceapi = component.find("workspace");
                        workspaceapi.openTab({
                            url: '/lightning/r/Contact/' +idContact +'/view' ,
                            focus: true
                        }).then(function(res) {
                            workspaceapi.openSubtab({
                                parentTabId: res,
                                url: '/lightning/n/TestAppPage',
                                focus: true
                            });
                        });
                        clearInterval(someTest);
                    }, 1);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("message", listener);
}
```

From here I am opening a subtab. This works fine.

**UPDATE**
For opening subtab: Its better if we write like this :

```
if (workspaceapi) {
    workspaceapi.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceapi.openSubtab({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            url: '/lightning/n/TestAppPage'
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```